# Android - positioning views programmatically

Tags: android, textview

I want to figure out how to position views programmatically in android. Lets say for example we have this XML code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/mainLayout">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="121dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
    android:text="Results" /></RelativeLayout>
```

How can I achieve this layout programmatically in android? because I want to have a random position of my textview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check this..

```
    RelativeLayout main = new RelativeLayout(this);
    main.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));



    TextView textV = new TextView(this);
        textV.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layoutParams.setMargins(121, 140, 0, 0);
    textV.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    text.setText("Result ");

main .addView(text);
```

Answer (score 7):

use the [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) with the setLayoutParams Method of the TextBox

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)textView1.getLayoutParams();
p.leftMargin = xxx; // in PX
p.topMargin = xxx; // in PX
textView1.setLayoutParams(p)
```

look up dp to px conversion if u want to use dp values

Comment: here you go, i hope that helps