# Android TextView: onClick after Moving TextView

Tags: java, android, onclick, textview

I'm trying to get my *textView* to react to a user's tap.

I found out that I actually have to set `android:clickable="true"`, so my function is actually called now.

But my problem is, that I'm using an animation to move my *textView* within my activity (from bottom to top). So now the *onClick* function is only called when you tap where my *textView* **used to be**, not where it actually is.

How do you fix this?

**EDIT:**
Unfortunately, I wasn't able to move the actual *TextView* programmatically (I'm using a *RelativeLayout*) like the first answer suggests.
However, I could overlay the position of my TextView with another TextView (transparent) that's clickable only when the animation comes to an end.
Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing animations the TextView is only visualy moved (the graphic rendering representation is only moved on the screen) but the real TextView object stays on the old position. You have to manually (programatically) move the TextView to the new position.

Take a look at [this presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=duefsFTJXzc) from Romain Guy and Chet Haase.

Chet Haase is taking about this issue at the 42:00 min. Take a look at the whole presentation if you have time. They are talking about some really usefull things.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this explains the issue. However, I can't set a new position for my TextView (app crashes). The error log says something about the RelativeLayout that I'm using. How do you do this?

Comment: When you are changing a views position programatically you have to set the LayoutParams. But the Layout Params have to be of the parent view. So if your TextView is in a RelativeLayout you have to set the TextView the RelativeLayout.LayoutParams. Take a look at this question maybe you will understand better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909741/android-positioning-views-programatically

I'm not sure if that's the problem, you should probably paste the whole error log.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do this. You didn't provide any code, so this will have to do. The key is setting bottomMargins to compensate.

```
Animation yourAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.your_anim_file);
slideOutBottom.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        animatedButton.clearAnimation();
        Resources r = view.getResources();
        int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, -68, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) animatedButton.getLayoutParams();
        lp.bottomMargin = -50;
        cartFunctionButtons.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
});
yourAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
animatedButton.startAnimation(yourAnimation);
```