# Placing textviews in background icon asset

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

For my app I wanted to have four blank octagons as backgrounds for my text views. I put the textviews in their correct places by using a relative layout and margins. The problem is that on different devices besides the device I worked(the 1020x1980) the textviews are off center. So I am wondering is the only way to fix this is by setting different margin values depending on the device (ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi etc etc) in a dimens.xml file?

[image]

[image]

code for the text views.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:background="@drawable/list_background"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight">


<!--Info for the octagon icons-->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="83dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:textColor="@color/orange_a400"
    android:layout_marginLeft="53dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"


    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:text="Aug 24"

    android:id="@+id/date" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"

    android:textColor="@color/orange_a400"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="105"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/sessionID"

    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sessionID"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/sessionID"
    android:textColor="@color/orange_a400"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="185"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/user_weight"
    />
```

Comment: I'd design each octagon to be a layout container and then put `TextView` inside it centered.

Comment: This is really an anti-pattern. You should use 4 textViews with their own octagon background and use relative positioning.

Comment: @Shaishav ... another layout? why? nesting layouts is **bad for performances**. TextViews can have their own background. No need for an extra layout...

Comment: @Rotwang i need some sleep i guess

Comment: @Rotwang ah thanks Im a bit new forgot textviews can have their own backgrounds as well. Ill try that.

Comment: Don't forget you'll need a dummy (invisible) View around which you will place the 4 "octagonal" TextViews.

Answer (score 0):

Use top and left position do this ,sequence of placing ,I mean to say first add      textview and set the position then add image set the position dynamically  and also refer this to set position

[ANDROID - positioning views programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909741/android-positioning-views-programatically)