# How can i change the position of a TextView through Java code?

Tags: java, android-studio, textview, position, android-constraintlayout

I want to change the position of A textView (in Java code, in Attribution to X and Y), After animating this view.

Software : Android Studio .

Layout : Constraint Layout .

How can i do this?

Comment: Hi Yonatan, I'm not sure I'd be able to help you but to help others that may be able to help you, what have you attempted so far?

Comment: Hey Yonatan, could you edit your question to include [minimal, compilable and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), e.g. with the code you wrote so far?

Comment: Not sure (your question is not very informative), but this may be what you are after: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909741/android-positioning-views-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say 'mytext' is your textView, then:

```
TextView thetext = findViewById(R.id.mytext);

thetext.setX(115 or whatever your X position is);
thetext.setY(325 or whatever your Y position is);
```